# Querying Allowed values for the possible fields of defects Using Java Rally rest API

Tags: java, rest, rally

I need to check if the field is having allowed values, if so need to get all the allowed values from the system using Java Rally rest API for eg : check if severity is having allowed values, if yes get the allowed values such as major problem, minor problem etc from the Rally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query against the TypeDefinition type.  Include Attributes and AllowedValues in your fetch.

```
QueryRequest defectTypeRequest = new QueryRequest("typedefinition");
defectTypeRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Attributes,Name,AllowedValues,StringValue"));
defectTypeRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("TypePath", "=", "defect"));
QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(defectTypeRequest);
```

Check out the TypeDefinition, AttributeDefinition and AllowedAttributeValue object in the [WSAPI docs](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) for a full list of the available fields to be fetched on each.

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thanks for the code, i've tried this option but i'm not getting the allowed values as null. My requirement is i need to get all the field names associated with a defect(Eg : Name,descriptio,severity) and then i've to check whether the field is having any allowed values, if so need to get those values