# Java Rally API - how to see all possible values of a custom field

Tags: java, rest, rally

I'm trying to get all possible values for a custom field dropdown using the rally REST api. When I run a GET call, all I get back for the response is the current selected value of the dropdown. Is there I way I can see all the possible values for this custom field? For example, if the field was called `Foo`, and the currently selected value was `bar1`, all I'm getting back in the JSON response is

```
"c_FOO" : "bar1"
```

when in reality the possible values of `Foo` could be `bar1`, `bar2`, etc. All I'm doing in code right now is

```
GetRequest getReq = new GetRequest("/porfolioitem/12345");
GetResponse getRes = rest.get(getReq);
System.out.print(getRes.getObject());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to pass in the project ID, since the workspace I work in has multiple projects. So, piggybacking off of what Kyle did,

```
restApi().getClient().doGet("/portfolioitem/1234/c_Foo/allowedvalues?project=project/" + projectId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check this existing question:
[Querying Allowed values for the possible fields of defects Using Java Rally rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141512/querying-allowed-values-for-the-possible-fields-of-defects-using-java-rally-rest?rq=1)

Basically you just need to load the type definition for your portfolio item type, then load its attributes collection, finding the specific attribute named 'c_Foo', then load that attributedefinition's allowedvalues collection.

Or this?

```
restApi.getClient().doGet("/portfolioitem/1234/c_Foo/allowedvalues")
```

You'll have to manually parse the results since that response format doesn't fit the standard wsapi Errors/Warnings/Results format.

Comment: Is `/c_Foo/AllowedValues` exposed in the Java API? I'm able to hit it from my browser.

Comment: oh, neat- i didn't even know you could hit allowed values right from an actual artifact.

Comment: I can hit it from the browser, but when I try to pass the web services link into my `get()` method I get the following error: "HTTP/1.1 404 Could not determine Web Services Version from 'v2.0https:'."

Comment: Hey Kyle, the above didn't work either. It returned an error that said "Attribute ‘c_Foo not found on ‘portfolioitem/feature/1234'"